# jquery slide from right to left with 2 sliders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On the right side of the slider 2, they must be disclosed from right to left, that would need to link (I've highlighted it in blue) at the same time put forward the content without interruption. Perhaps not offered the best option solutions would be very grateful for your options. thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/vR3Mu/

```
$(function () {
    $(".side_link").click(function () {
        $_side = $(this).parents(".side");
        $(this).animate({"right":200},990);
        $(".side_content", $_side).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/EbKL4/